# Linked List containing another linked list, nested linked list

Tags: c

My assignment is to create a Main Linked List containing groups, and a secondary Linked List containing the student and their data. 
My idea was to make both of them in separate programs, they run perfectly, however, I have to merge them into one, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

I tried adding a Student type * next pointer on the main structure, to no avail. I've also tried sending both Lists to a function, but nothing good.

```
    typedef struct Group_type
{
    int group_Num;
    char career_Name[50];
    struct Alumno_type * link;//Apuntador a lista de alumnos
    struct Group_type * next;
    struct Group_type * prev;
} Group;
///LISTA SECUNDARIA SIMPLE
typedef struct Alumno_type
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    int no_lista;
    struct Alumno_type * next;
}Alumno;
typedef struct LinkedList_type
{
    struct Group_type * first;
    struct Group_type * last;
} LinkedList;
typedef struct LinkedList2_type
{
    struct Alumno_type * first;
    struct Alumno_type * last;
} LinkedList2;
///FUNCIONES LISTA PRINCIPAL
LinkedList * create_List();
Group * create_Group (int, char *);
void add_Group(LinkedList *, int, char *);
Bool remove_Group(LinkedList *, int);

///FUNCIONES LISTA SECUNDARIA
LinkedList2 * create_List2();
void add_Alumno(LinkedList2 *, char *, int, int, int, LinkedList *);
void print_Alumnos(LinkedList2 *, int, LinkedList *);
void main()

///FUNCTIOM I NEED HELP WITH
void add_Alumno(LinkedList2 * this, char * name, int age, int no_lista,int group_num, LinkedList * GList)
{
    //creo un nodo para insertar
    Group * tmp  = GList->first; //Moverme por la lista de grupos
    Alumno * it=this->first;
    Alumno * newAlumno=new_Alumno(name, age, no_lista);
    if(!this)
    {
        printf("Lista no creada\n");
    }
    for (it = this->first; it != NULL; it = it->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(it->name, name)==0) //Evitar repeticiC3n
        {
            printf ("Alumno repetido\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    if(this->first == NULL)
    {
        //printf("ENTRA");
        newAlumno->next=NULL;
        this->last=newAlumno;
        this->first=newAlumno;
        //first y last ocupan el mismo valor, siguiente apunta a nulo
        //solo si la lista está vacía
        //printf("ENTRA");
        if(GList->first->next != NULL) //Si no es el único grupo pero el primer alumno
        {
            do
            {
               if(group_num == tmp->group_Num)//Encuentra grupo
               {
                    printf("ENTRA\n");
                    tmp->link = this->last;
                    tmp->link->next = NULL;
                    print_Alumnos(this, group_num, GList);
               }
               tmp = tmp->next;
            }
            while(tmp != GList->first);
        }
        else
        {
            if(group_num == tmp->group_Num)//Encuentra grupo
               {
                    printf("ENTRA 2\n");
                    tmp->link = this->last;
                    tmp-> link->next = NULL;
                    print_Alumnos(this, group_num, GList);
               }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this->last->next=newAlumno;
        this->last=this->last->next;
        if(GList->first->next != NULL) //Si no es el único grupo pero hay alumnos
        {
            do
            {
               if(group_num == tmp->group_Num)//Encuentra grupo
               {
                    printf("ENTRA no es primer al\n");
                    tmp->link = this->last;
                    tmp-> link->next = NULL;
                    print_Alumnos(this, group_num, GList);
               }
               tmp = tmp->next;
            }
            while(tmp != GList->first);
        }
        else
        {
            if(group_num == tmp->group_Num)//Encuentra grupo
               {
                    printf("ENTRA no es primer al 2\n");
                    tmp->link = this->last;
                    tmp-> link->next = NULL;
                    print_Alumnos(this, group_num, GList);
               }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected outcome is to have a Node from the main list, containing a list of all the students of that particular group.

Comment: Also I have to keep in mind, the main list is a Doubly Circular list, the secondary is a singly linked list!

Comment: I like this approach, instead of embedding data in your list, embed list on your data, then you can simply add as many as linked list to your data as you want. See the kernel linked list implementation, is wonderful https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LinkedLists

Comment: What do you get instead of the expected outcome, what did you try to resolve your problem? It would be nice to provide a [example] to not let us waste our time.

Comment: How many `typedef struct Node_type Node` do you have? That's not going to work.

Comment: I edited the post so you don't feel like you're wasting your time :/